# How point multiple directories in htaccess using if else condition in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to point multiple directory using the htaccess.

suppose i have two directory AAA and BBB.

if ( in url "AAA" is present ) point directory AAA;
else Point directory BBB.

Is it possible ??

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
# make sure mod_rewrite is on
RewriteEngine On

# check request URI for AAA and rewrite to /AAA/ (only once)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/AAA.*
RewriteRule (.*)           /AAA/$1   [L]

# otherwise rewrite to /BBB/
RewriteRule (.*)           /BBB/$1
```

Also, you might want to try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^[^A]+AAA.*
```

instead of the first line, as I can't remember if they're a `/` at the front of `RewriteRule`s or not...